# How to fit data into normal distribution in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have data as:

```
X   -4  -3  -2   -1    0    1    2   3   4

Y   10  36  91  223  444  254  108  43  10
```

I wish to fit this into a normal distribution in R, get its parameters and curve fitting error, and plot the curve. What is the best way to do this? I see that I am not using fitdist or fitdistr correctly.

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done? Also what is your actual goal? To transform your data so that is is approximately normal or to see how close to normal the data are?

Comment: Wish to understand how close the data is to a normal distribution. I have tried multiple approaches and fallen into errors. Must I do some transformations to the data to work with R? R is too detailed for that.

Comment: have you looked at `?qqnorm`?

Comment: I have not looked at qqnorm, let me check it, thx

Comment: qqnorm: What are the variables I must use to get the curve parameters and error?

Answer (score 1):

qqnorm may be your answer, as in:

```
# random normal variables fit the line quite well
qqnorm(rnorm(50));abline(0,1)

# random uniformly distributed variables do not
qqnorm(runif(50));abline(0,1)

# Q-Q plot with your data
qqnorm(Y);abline(0,1)
```

Comment: Given my data, can you give me details of what to give the parameters to qqnorm to get the error in normal distribution curve fitting?

Comment: you just need to supply your variable (`Y`), and the quantiles of your variable will be compared to quantiles of a normally distributed variable.  If you're having trouble understanding the QQ plot, there is a [nice Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) on QQ plots.

Comment: Did you mean to use a different distribution function on your second line? You are currently using `rnorm` in both.

Comment: @jdobres Yep, fixed